# Как заменить jqery на нативный js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

посдкажите пожалуйста как зменить $(this).find('.terms__btn').addClass('hover-btn') на нативный js. Заране большое спасибо.

```js
const terms = document.querySelectorAll('.terms');

for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i ++) {
terms[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).find('.terms__btn').addClass('hover-btn');
});

terms[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).find('.terms__btn').removeClass('hover-btn');
});
}
```

```css
.hover-btn {
  background-color: var(--violet);
}
```

```html
<div class="terms terms-min">
<span class="terms__title"></span>
<span class="terms__price"><span class="terms__cost"></span><span class="terms__currency"></span></span>
<p class="terms__description">
</p><ul class="terms__list">
<li class="terms__item">123</li>
<li class="terms__item">123</li>
<li class="terms__item">13123</li>
<li class="terms__item">123</li>
<li class="terms__item">123</li>
</ul><p></p>
<div class="terms__button">
<a href="/" class="terms__btn">Заказать</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
el.currentTarget.querySelector('.terms__btn').classList.add('hover-btn');
```

и

```
el.currentTarget.querySelector('.terms__btn').classList.remove('hover-btn');
```

где el - аргумент колбэк функции, т.е. `function(el)`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Подскажите приавильно ли я понял я добавляю в function(el) аргумент и потом el.querySelector('.terms__btn').classList.add('hover-btn') добавляю и удаляю класс по наведению. Но у меня почему-то сыпет ошибка Uncaught TypeError: el.querySelector is not a function

Comment: el.target или el.currentTarget

Comment: @WilliamBradley да, чуть ошибся я... el.target.... можно и `terms[i]` использовать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо вам огромне. el.target сыпал тоже ошибку, а el.currentTarget сработал идеально без ошибок.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey спасибо большое ! el.currentTarget  сработал идельаное.

Comment: @WilliamBradley Еще можно `this.querySelector(...)`